# Define where placed the c-string

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c-strings

How can I define do I need call "delete [ ]" for pointer or not in destructor of my class?
Pointer (member-variable) can point out to buffer allocated in heap or not in different time (it can be a literal in read-only memory or a literal placed in stack).
What the best way to resolve it?
Do I need use just another flag for it or may be get addresses of heap boundry and  check if buffer address between them?
Or there is more rational way?

Comment: If your pointer points to character data, you can avoid the entire issue by using `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Comment: But I use it for socket data transfer and one buffer can hold character data (command in ASCII) and just bytes in another time.

Comment: Excellent! It sounds like `std::string` is the way to go, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot tell if a pointer is on the automatic store, in static memory, or in dynamic memory simply by looking at the pointer. You need to store a flag at the time when you set that pointer - for example, like this:

```
class classWithDynamicData {
private:
    bool needToDelete;
    char strData[];
public:
    classWithDynamicData(int size) : needToDelete(true), strData(new char[size]) {
    }
    classWithDynamicData(char* data) : needToDelete(false), strData(data) {
    }
    ~classWithDynamicData() {
        if (needToDelete) delete[] strData;
    }
    ...
    // You need to define a copy constructor and an assignment operator
    // to avoid violating the rule of three
};
```

Comment: Not directly related, but this solution violates the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use dynamically allocated member(*Use `std::string` instead of `char *` or `std::vector` instead of dynamically allocated data member*) or
2. Use smart pointers

Comment: Use std::string to handle the dynamic allocation instead. No need for (smart) pointers here.

Comment: @AnotherTest: True but OP didn't say he is using a `char *`, so its only your guess.

Comment: ah all the answers/responses seemed to be about `char*` which probably caused me to think this. You should add "use standard containers if possible" to the answer though (if you want an upvote ;)).

Comment: @AnotherTest: Not for the upvote but for the correctness I modified the answer.

Comment: I use `char* buf`, but it can point out to not only correct character string (include thos case when: `buf = "literal"`), it can contain just bytes also when: `buf = new char [SIZE]`).